# Exception in SonarQube.Msbuild.Runner

Tags: windows, exception, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

Running the SonarQube.MsBuild.Runner.exe I get the following exception:

```
Using environment variables to determine the download directory...
Creating the analysis bin directory:

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace.
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.preprocess(ILogger logger, IBootstrapperSettings settings, String[] args)
   at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have the environment variables SONAR_RUNNER_HOME and SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS set like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
SONAR_RUNNER_HOME              C:\Program Files\SonarQube\sonar-runner-2.4
SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS              -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

What is missing?

Comment: Are you calling SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe from within TFS 2013? Version 0.9 does not yet support to be called in a standalone way (and will crash).

Comment: I have a prebuild powershell script that is called from TFS 2013 that will call SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe. It fails when it is called from the TFS 2013 build or from the Powershell command line.

Comment: Does the analysis succeed if you call the SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe directly from the TFS build definition i.e. not via the powershell script?

Comment: No, it does not succeed either, There is no error message, not even entries in the sonar.log are produced. I would not be able to do it this way anyway, because I need to do more than just execute sonar.

Comment: Have a look at the troubleshooting notes in this post: Http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843177/sonar-and-tfs-2013-no-projectinfo-xml-files-were-found/30894558#30894558.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Sonar.MsBuild.Runner 1.0 now. The problem does not exist in MsBuild Runner.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the space in C:\Program Files\SonarQube\sonar-runner-2.4 ?
Try to add quotation mark around the path or move the location of SonarQube runner to C:\SonarQube\sonar-runner-2.4

Also verify that you are not running Java 8, because then you should remove the SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS variable as described on page 20 here https://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1452516